# Nest and Elastic Search - Mapping

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to map multiple analyzers to a field in my elastic type. If I use an ElasticAttribute to map an analyzer:

```
[ElasticProperty(Analyzer = "fulltext")]
public string LongDescription { get; set; }
```

and I look at the request created I get:

```
"name": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "fulltext"
    },
```

In order to map multiple analyzers to the same field, I use Fluent mapping and add a multifield:

```
.Properties(prop => prop
                    .MultiField(mf => mf
                        .Name(p => p.Name)
                        .Fields(f => f
                            .String(
                                s =>
                                    s.Name(n => n.Name)
                                        .IndexAnalyzer("autocomplete_analyzer")
                                        .IncludeInAll(false)
                                        .Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed))
                            .String(
                                s =>
                                    s.Name(n => n.Name)
                                        .IndexAnalyzer("fulltext")
                                        .IncludeInAll(false)
                                        .Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed))
                        )
                    )
                )
```

The request generated looks like this:

```
 "name": {
      "type": "multi_field",
      "fields": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "index_analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer",
          "include_in_all": false
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "index_analyzer": "fulltext",
          "include_in_all": false
        }
      }
    },
```

I am specifically interested in the "analyzer"/"index_analyzer" properties. With fluent mapping, I can only set IndexAnalyzer or SearchAnalyzer. I understand the difference between IndexAnalyzer and SearchAnalyzer, but what is the "analyzer" property when I use an ElasticAttribute? Does that just mean the Index and Search are set the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specifying `analyzer` is indeed setting `index_analyzer` and `search_analyzer` at the same time. `analyzer` is an elasticsearch property and not some magic behavior from NEST.

The fluent mapping is missing the `.Analyzer()` method, this is now added in 1.0!