# modify the _mapping in Elastic Search shows strange behavior

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-marvel

I have modified a field type of CompanyName in PoCo in c# (NEST) from string to int (just for testing). first thing is that it is not reflecting in mapping of type. it is still showing string there

```
    "properties": {
       "AddressNumber": {
          "type": "string"
       },
       "City": {
          "type": "string"
       },
       "CompanyName": {
          "type": "string"
       },
       "ContactName": {
          "type": "string"
       },
```

But **it does allow me** to save the integer value of CompanyName. In marvel also, the data is showing like int.

Previous Document in ES

```
             {  "CompanyName": "1231",
               "ContactName": "sdfsdf",
               "City": "Schenectady"
             }
```

Last saved document after changing the field type to int

```
                 { "CompanyName": 1231,
                   "ContactName": "shivang",
                   "City": "Leeds"
                 }
```

It is searching fine with string and int values,If we try to save some string in it, it is showing CompanyName as 0 ( which is fine ). But why it is not showing the mapping correctly?

NOTE : I did not recreated the index. It is the existing index

Comment: Did you recreated index? More info [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime).

Comment: @Rob: No, I did not recreated the index. It is the existing index

Comment: You should do this after mapping changes, more details why and what for in above link.

Comment: @Rob: Yeah, i got that. I was just wondering about the behavior of elastic search

Answer (score 1):

[Changing Mapping With Zero Downtime](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime/) will explain this thoroughly, as pointed out by @Rob here and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519318/elastic-search-nest-map-update-string-property-as-not-analysed) SO question.

I highly recommend reading about [default mapping](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/default-mapping.html), [dynamic mapping](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html), and especially [dynamic templates](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-templates). I find this really helps me keep my code clean from attributes or mapping code and let my poco's be poco's!